# Bug with rendering a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

This is what I see when viewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483295/memory-leak-while-using-threads) which Chrome and IE

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

Chrome Version: 37.0.2062.103 m

IE Version: 11.0.9600.17207

Is only me or something wrong with that question?

It does looks fine in editing mode.

[image]

Comment: I saw it too, using IE11 on Windows 8.1. Looks like the font used for the code block keeps getting used beyond the end of the post. Fixed now by @BoltClock.

Comment: Not sure if I should mark this [status-completed] or [status-bydesign]. I suppose I'll leave it to one of the devs.

Comment: @BoltClock This is an artifact of a particularly buggy version of the Markdown parser that was present back when the post was created. Long since fixed.

Comment: @animuson: So in other words, [status-completed] to refer to the Markdown parser bug that was fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Markdown renderer is updated occasionally, and some of these changes tend to break the HTML output of some very old posts because the output is rendered only once and then cached until the next edit. This is perfectly harmless; a simple edit will force the post to be re-rendered, restoring the post to its former glory.

You can even undo the edit after submitting it (such that it leaves an "[Edit removed during grace period]" in the revision history) and the post will still be fixed, but I prefer to leave the edit in so the edit summary can be preserved.