# Formatted as code in preview, but not in answer

Tags: support, answers, code-formatting

Today, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724482/3049655) when browsing through some questions.

Since it is not formatted as code, I pressed the edit button and was astonished to see that it was already indented by four spaces and the preview shows the formatted code.

I tried to reproduce this in an answer, but could not, as an answer has to be at least 30 characters long.

- Why isn't the code formatted properly in the answer, but is, in the preview?
- How did that user post an answer less than 30 characters long?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Because the HTML is cached, not rendered on the fly: [Bug with rendering a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270890/bug-with-rendering-a-question/270892#270892)
2. Most likely because at that time Stack Overflow, [in its blissful youth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30128/how-old-is-stackoverflow), was *happy* to receive *any* answer – even such a short one.